# Photutils Source Detection doesnt work for small pic, works for large, why?

Tags: python, image-processing, physics, astronomy, astropy

I am trying to detect stars/astronomical objects on a picture.
This is the picture where I can do it well, as outlined below:

[image: pic like Hubble Deep Field]

Following the advice [given on this site](https://photutils.readthedocs.io/en/stable/detection.html) I have this code:

```
from astropy.stats import sigma_clipped_stats
from photutils.datasets import make_100gaussians_image
from photutils import find_peaks
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.visualization import simple_norm
from astropy.visualization.mpl_normalize import ImageNormalize
from photutils import CircularAperture
data = make_100gaussians_image()
mean, median, std = sigma_clipped_stats(data, sigma=3.0)
threshold = median + (5. * std)
tbl = find_peaks(data, threshold, box_size=11)
positions = (tbl['x_peak'], tbl['y_peak'])
apertures = CircularAperture(positions, r=5.)
norm = simple_norm(data, 'sqrt', percent=99.9)
plt.imshow(data, cmap='Greys_r', origin='lower', norm=norm)
apertures.plot(color='#0547f9', lw=1.5)
plt.xlim(0, data.shape[1]-1)
plt.ylim(0, data.shape[0]-1)
```

It works fine, this is the output:

[image: lots of stars with some marked]

If I modify line 10 to be `threshold = median + (30. * std)` then I get an output with much fewer stars marked, as expected. This is the output:

[image]

Now, I want to use it for this file:

[image: pic with two stars]

For this I run this code, source is loaded from a FITS file:

```
import lightkurve
tpf=lightkurve.targetpixelfile.KeplerTargetPixelFile('ktwo201103700-c102_lpd-targ.fits')
from astropy.stats import sigma_clipped_stats
from photutils.datasets import make_100gaussians_image
from photutils import find_peaks
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.visualization import simple_norm
from astropy.visualization.mpl_normalize import ImageNormalize
from photutils import CircularAperture
#data = make_100gaussians_image()
data = tpf.flux[100]
mean, median, std = sigma_clipped_stats(data, sigma=3.0)
threshold = median + (0.1 * std)
tbl = find_peaks(data, threshold, box_size=11)
#tbl['peak_value'].info.format = '%.8g'  # for consistent table output
#print(tbl[:10])    # print only the first 10 peaks
positions = (tbl['x_peak'], tbl['y_peak'])
apertures = CircularAperture(positions, r=1.)
norm = simple_norm(data, 'sqrt', percent=99.9)
plt.imshow(data, cmap='Greys_r', origin='lower', norm=norm)
apertures.plot(color='#0547f9', lw=1.5)
plt.xlim(0, data.shape[1]-1)
plt.ylim(0, data.shape[0]-1)
```

The output is below. No matter how small treshold I give in line 13, it **only finds one star, not two**, as would be desired.

[image: two stars, one is circled]

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **box_size=4** I have this result: [image: 3stars]

I had to install these modules before running your script in **jupyter notebook**:

```
pip3 install jupyter lightkurve photutils
```

– and used this command also to see the image result:

```
plt.interactive(True)
%matplotlib
```

Comment: From here: https://photutils.readthedocs.io/en/stable/background.html:
"Photutils provides the Background2D class to estimate the 2D background and background noise in an astronomical image. Background2D requires the size of the box (box_size) in which to estimate the background. Selecting the box size requires some care by the user. The box size should generally be larger than the typical size of sources in the image, but small enough to encapsulate any background variations." Not on the page about source detection, but still I think this explains the issue.